# System call after final document shipout

Tags: compiling

I am looking for some trick to do a system call after the document is finalized. The idea is that the finished document is copied or converted or emailed or whatever without a shell script or batch file.

The following MWE explains what I try to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% just an example for a system call
\newcommand{\mycall}{%
  \immediate\write18{copy /Y \jobname.pdf dummy.pdf}
}

\AfterEndDocument{\mycall}

\begin{document}
Hello World.
\end{document}
```

I know that this MWE gives not the desired result because `\AfterEndDocument` is still too early. I would like to place `\mycall` after the final shipout, if possible.

I also know a workaround, i.e. writing the document content in a separate file and compile that file (the TikZ `externalize` approach), but is it possible to do such a call from within the original document? Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you. I did not find this myself. I think it's the same question - I still have to check the answers.

Comment: The accepted answer of the other question is also the answer to my question - and it is really quite clever!